# Use gradient to find a vector equation of the normal line to the circle through the point

Tags: calculus

Use gradient to find a vector equation of the normal line to 
the circle $$\ {x^2} +{y^2} = 1 $$ through the point P = (4, 3)

After solving it, I think the vector equation is :

$$ \vec r(t)=<4,3> + t<4,3>, \qquad t \in \mathbb{R} $$

How would I show that the distance btw the circle and the point is 4 using the vector equation??

[image]

Comment: Where does this line intersect the circle?

Comment: I am just typing it wrong. sorry. i will link the photo.

Comment: No need for a photo. That was a hint as to how to proceed.

Comment: I know Q = (1, 0) would satisfy x^2+y^2 = 1

Comment: That point isn’t on the line that you’ve calculated, though. You need to find a $t$ such that $\|\vec r(t)\|=1$. Alternatively, you might note that this line passes through the origin.

Comment: that means to find the vector unit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37363/discussion-between-user3773246-and-amd).